# How do I move keyframes on multiple frames? v2.8

Tags: keyframes

In 2.79 I have keyframes between 40 and 50 and I box select those frames then I grab 1 of the selected keyframe and drag them all to the left or right where I want them.

In 2.80 I have keyframes between 40 and 50 and I box select those frames then I grab 1 of the selected keyframe and it deselect all keyframes except keys on the same keyframe number.

So what is the 2.8 method to dragging multiple keyframes in the same manner as 2.79?

Answer (score 1):

Select the keyframes you want to grab, then press G and move the mouse, confirm with left click. After pressing G you can enter the value of frames of the movement, then press enter to confirm. The new behaviour is consequence of the new general left click approach.

Comment: Could not google to find this answer, thanks!