# How to move selected keyframes to current frame or a specified frame number

Tags: keyframes, timeline

I want to select keyframes from multiple different frames and move them all to a specific time without having to use `g` or `s`. I have a specific frame in mind that I want to move all of the selected keyframes to, but am not sure what keyboard shortcut will make this possible.

Steps to recreate:

1. Create multiple keyframes at frame 1, 2, 3, and 4
2. Select multiple keyframes from frame 1 and 2
3. Set timeline current frame to frame 3
4. (Keyboard shortcut here) to move selected keyframes to current frame

*Not* looking for this as a solution [How do I move keyframes on multiple frames? v2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153410/how-do-i-move-keyframes-on-multiple-frames-v2-8)

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK there is no shortcut, you would have to use G as explained in the linked Q&A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hovering on the action editor or dopesheet you can select the keyframes you want to move, set the time cursor to the desired frame and press S,X,0,Enter.

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you - Trying to determine how this reads. "scale on the x-axis of the timeline to zero, aka the current frame"?

Comment: Yes, current frame is the pivot point, if you scale on X axis until 0 you reach it.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> also works. Like you would operate your 3D cursor.